# Simulate F1 kepress on active control to load help system - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

We are adding a help button to the toolbar of our application.

When the user clicks on this button, we need to load the help system for the control that they were on

For example, if they are on the address box of the contacts form, I need to load the help system for this using its context id

I was thinking about trying to mimic an F1 keypress which would then take care of the context id element of things and load the help file

However, I cant get this to work because it tries to load the help based on the active control not the one I was on, i.e. the contact address

Is there a way to do this?  Essentially I need to send an F1 keypress from previously active control (assuming that the currently active control is my toolbar button)

We are using Delphi 2010

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need a tool button `OnClick` handler that can be as simple as this:

```
procedure TMyForm.ToolButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(ActiveControl) then begin
    Application.HelpContext(ActiveControl.HelpContext);
  end;
end;
```

What makes this work is the fact that the controls on a toolbar do not ever become the active control.

Comment: Thanks this works in terms of bringing up the help system.  However, the help button is on the toolbar of the main form.  When I use this code, the help system is called with the help for the form which is being viewed, even though I have focus in a control that has its own context sensitive help? If I am on the grid and press F1 I get help for the grid

Comment: I  tested the code when I wrote the answer. It works. There must be something unusual in your app.

Comment: Hi David its fine now this worked, I just had to write some code that goes back up the control's hierarchy.  We use DevExpress grids, so the active control in my case was a cell in the grid, I needed to go back up to the parent, i.e. the grid

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with your toolbar. The system toolbar doesn't ordinarily get the focus — it's never the active control. If you're using a real `TToolBar` and `TToolButton`, you won't have this problem. Even `TSpeedButton` won't have this problem. Use the right control for the job.

Also, don't try to "simulate" a keyboard event. Just call `Application.HelpContext` directly.

Comment: Thanks for this Rob, however, as I just mentioned above I have a problem now where application.contextid appears to be 1 level too high? Instead of being the grid's context id it is the parent form's id?

Comment: There are question marks in your comments, but I don't know what question you're asking.

Comment: Hi Rob I was trying to figure out why the context number was wrong, but as explained above I have sorted it now thanks for your help